# Upgrade to 20.04 throws dhcpcd error

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, dhcpd

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and on reboots I receive the following internal error. Everything continues to work normally, so I just dismiss it, but I was hoping to understand the root cause and fix it.

The machine is currently connected via ethernet. Are there any steps I can do to help debug this? If you need any more information from the error message I can provide it, I haven't found an easy way to copy the information out.

Executable Path:
/usr/sbin/dhcpcd
[image]

Comment: This would most likely be classified as a bug, which makes it outside the scope of this site. That said, if you'd like to send some follow-up data to Canonical, you can [report the problem](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en) directly to them. Hopefully this will help the team behind `dhcpcd` find a solution to your problem 